# calculating average using awk from multiple files

Tags: awk

I have 500 files with name fort.1, fort.2 ... fort.500. Each file contains 800 data as below:

> 1   0.485
>      2   0.028
>      3   0.100
>      4   0.979
>      5   0.338
>      6   0.891
>      7   0.415
>      8   0.368
>      9   0.245
>     10   0.489

I want to get the average of each line of second column from every file. In other words, get average of second column first line from all files and store in "output.file". Then get average of second column of second line and store in the same "output.file". 
I tried with paste command but fail to get what I want.
IS there any way to do in AWK?

Appreciate any help.
Thanks

Answer (score 8):

awk without any assumption on the 1st column:

```
awk '{a[FNR]+=$2;b[FNR]++;}END{for(i=1;i<=FNR;i++)print i,a[i]/b[i];}' fort.*
```

Comment: Does this code consider all "first line of all input files (fort.1, fort.2...)" and calculate the average and subsequently goes to second line of all files (fort.1, fort.2....) until 800 lines from each file? I need some explanation to understand what this code does actually. Thanks

Comment: @Vijay : It indeed does..updated it with the fort.* to make it more clear. You can test it against a small sample file to confirm...

Comment: Guru, This code works fine. Thank you. Additionally small thing need to be added. I have files with names fort.1, fort.2 and so on. I afraid if I put fort.*, it will read  fort.1, fort.10, fort.100 instead of fort.1, fort.2 and so on. How this can be treated? Thanks

Comment: @Vijay : fort.* will read fort.1,fort.2,...fort.10, fort.100,etc.. Every file beginning with fort. will be read, and this is what I think you want as well.

Comment: If it does read fort.10 and fort.100 before fort.2, it should not matter for the final average.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a quick way using `paste` and `awk`:

```
paste fort.* | awk '{ for(i=2;i<=NF;i+=2) array[$1]+=$i; if (i = NF) print $1, array[$1]/NF*2 }' > output.file
```

Like some of the other answers; here's another way but this one uses `sort` to get numerically sorted output:

```
awk '{ sum[$1]+=$2; cnt[$1]++ } END { for (i in sum) print i, sum[i]/cnt[i] | "sort -n" }' fort.*
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the first column is an ID:

```
cat fort.* | awk '{sum[$1] += $2; counts[$1]++;} END {for (i in sum) print i, sum[i]/counts[i];}'
```

Answer (score 1):

My understanding: each file is a set of measurements at a particular location.  You want to aggregate the measurements across all locations, averaging the value the same row in each file into a new file.

Assuming the first column can be treated as an ID for the row (and there are 800 measurements in a file):

```
cat fort.* | awk '
BEGIN { 
    for (i = 1; i <= 800; i++)
        total[i] = 0
}

{ total[$1] += $2 } 

END {
    for (i = 1; i <= 800; i++)
        print i, total[i]/500
}
'
```

First, we initialize an array to store the sum for a row across all files.

Then, we loop through the concatenated files.  We use the first column as a key for the row, and we sum into the array.

Finally, we loop over the array and print the average value by row across all files.

Comment: In this code what I understand is that at first all the values from fort.1 file keep in array "total". Next it goes to read the second file fort.2 and keep in array total. (For example), then it shall do (total[1] + total[1] /2) from first and second file respectively, to get the average. But I dont get this... Sorry if I understood incorrectly.

Comment: Edited to reflect my assumptions around the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply. Let me again clarify what I want. Each file (total 500 files) contains two columns (1st column and 2nd column) and with 800 rows of lines. I want the first line, 2nd column of each file (all 500 files) to be added and calculate the average and store in a newfile as average.output. Then it goes to second line, 2nd column of all files (500 files) and calculate the average and store in average.output. And it continues until the average.output file contain 800 lines. Wish you get this explanation. Sorry if my question in the post confused you. Thank you in advance.