# AWK to average over columns from multiple files

Tags: awk

I have similar multiple files e.g. c1.txt, c2.txt.... etc and I want to average each line of the 7th column of all the files and write the output in another file. Each file has 45120 rows or lines. To calculate the sum of 7th column I write:

```
awk '{a[FNR]+=$7;b[FNR]++;}END{for(i=1;i<=FNR;i++)print a[i]/b[i];}' c* > ave_result.txt
```

It then prints out half of the average of each line of the 7th column and it prints only unto line 264. I checked the output of line 264 and it is not printing even the half of the average of those files.

How should I modify the awk command to calculate the correct average of each lines in the 7th column ? Thank you. 
For example, few lines of the 1st file is

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 2.559346e-08 2.080054e-10
1 1 1 1 1 2 1.398551e-09 2.709745e-09
1 1 1 1 1 3 -7.939651e-10 -1.560374e-09
```

and similar in the 2nd file :

```
2 1 1 1 1 1 2.579924e-08 2.756949e-09
2 1 1 1 1 2 -1.333798e-10 1.700513e-09
2 1 1 1 1 3 2.334223e-09 -3.592740e-09
```

and SO ON. I would like to calculate average of the 7th column of all the files I have. SO the expected output is

```
2.579924e-08
6.3259e-10
6.3259e-10
```

Now how to edit the awk command if I have 200 such files and each file has 45120 rows?

Comment: edit your question to show sample data for your problem. We should only need to see 2-3 lines of data, and 5-7 fields per line. THEN include your expected output from that input. Good luck.

Comment: Do you have files with less than 7 columns?

Comment: why not `{sum+=$7;}END{print sum/NR}` ...plus whatever u need to account for formatting and blank or useless data lines... can't go much further without specifics.

Comment: I have added sample calculation in the edited question. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### If you want to get the average of col7 in each file:

you set `a[] and b[]` with one file, but you didn't clear them when started processing new file. so the result won't be correct.  In fact, array is not needed for this problem. you could try this (I didn't test):

```
awk 'FNR==1{if(s!=0)print s/c; s=0;c=0}{s+=$7;c++}END{print s/c}' c* > result.txt
```

#### If you want to get average of col7 from **all** files:

```
awk '{s+=$7}END{print s/NR}' c* > result.txt
```

### EDIT

as @PM77-1 commented, I might not understand your requirement right. If you want to have 45120 output lines, it is like

```
sum $7 of all line 1 from all files, and get average, output line 1
sum $7 of all line 2 from all files, and get average, output line 2
...
sum $7 of all line 45120 from all files, and get average, output line 45120
```

You don't need the `b[]` actually. you can either use a counter to calculate the count of files or use gawk's `ARGC`

```
awk '{a[FNR]+=$7}END{for(i=1;i<=FNR;i++)print a[i]/(ARGC-1);}' c* >...
```

Comment: OP states: "*I want to average each line of the 7th column of all the files*", so it will be averaging across the files on the same line.

Comment: @PM77-1 then my 2nd awk cmd should do it, right? it output single line, which is the average of the col7 in all files.

Comment: Nope. S/he wants 45120 averages. One per line (not per file).

Comment: @PM77-1 I think I got you, so the output should have 45120 lines, and line 1 is the average of col7 in **first** line among all input files.

Comment: Yes, this is **my** understanding.

Comment: Similar to [calculating average of same lines of second column from many files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13266168/calculating-average-of-same-lines-of-second-column-from-many-files?rq=1)