# Averaging tab separated values

Tags: tabs, notation, exponential, csv

I have several files from `Acquire1_00001.txt` ... `Acquire1_00050.txt`

The values in there are all tab separated like this:

```
3.500E2 -2.3386E0
3.510E2 39.192E-2
3.520E2 -46.143E-2
3.530E2 -42.809E-4
3.540E2 2.9356E0
3.550E2 1.0014E0
3.560E2 -1.3001E0
3.570E2 4.5244E0
```

Now I am trying to average all the files into a new file. So far the exponential notation of the values is driving me crazy. What can I do?

Comment: I solved it with this:

`awk '{ sum[$1]+=$2; cnt[$1]++ } END { for (i in sum) print i, sum[i]/cnt[i] | "sort -n" }' Acquire1_* > out.data`

Which I found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13263963/calculating-average-using-awk-from-multiple-files/13264259#13264259

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty standard [`E-notation`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E_notation) that lots of software understands.

It's easy enough to convert to a standard decimal notation with a script on unix, though you will lose some precision (1e-100 would print 0.00000, for instance):

```
 awk '{ printf "%.40f %.40f\n", $1, $2}' < e-notation-file.txt > d-notation-file.txt
```

Comment: Thanks, I have found out that a precision of `%.6f` is enough for this data.