# awk average same column in multiple files(with certain range)

Tags: bash, awk, average

As I said, I got answer from here:
[AWK multiple files averge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13263963/calculating-average-using-awk-from-multiple-files)

However, that is not enough if I have multiple files `dummy_0.txt dummy_100.txt dummy_200.txt... dummy_5000.txt ... dummy_50000.txt`.
I only want to average column 2 of files range from `dummy_0.txt to dummy_5000.txt.`

Instead of doing this:

```
awk '{a[FNR]+=$2;b[FNR]++;}END{for(i=1;i<=FNR;i++)print i,a[i]/b[i];}' dummy_*.txt
```

I need something like where interval is 100

```
awk '{a[FNR]+=$2;b[FNR]++;}END{for(i=1;i<=FNR;i++)print i,a[i]/b[i];}' dummy_[100 - 5000].txt
```

How can I do it?

Comment: @anubhava lets say 100 to 5000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use glob range `{start..end..interval}` in bash:

```
awk '{a[FNR]+=$2; b[FNR]++}
   END{for(i=1;i<=FNR;i++) print i,a[i]/b[i]}' dummy_{100..5000..100].txt
```

Comment: however, my interval is 100 between files

Comment: thank you, I was also thought about the same thing, however, I put interval in the middle instead of end...

Comment: Wait...I think that is not working...I got this error `awk: can't open file dummy.{100..5000..100}.txt`

Comment: Glob range is only available in bash 4+

Comment: @123 do you have any ideas?

Comment: @Lbj_x `{{1..9}00,{1..4}{0..9}00,5000}`