# Bash: unable to recognise filename with range using calculation

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sed

I am trying to do multiple files calculation with `awk`: [awk average same column in multiple files(with certain range)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35599505/awk-average-same-column-in-multiple-fileswith-certain-range)

awk is trying to fetch file list from my range `avg_x.{1..1000}.dat`.
Now, I find a problem. if I write range explicitly:

```
awk ' {a[$1]+=$8;b[$1]++;}END{for(i=1;i<=(FNR-1);i++)print i,a[i]/b[i];}' avg_x.{1..1000}.dat
```

It works perfectly.
However, if I add some calculation inside using bash expression it is not working:

```
i=0
interval=1000    
awk ' {a[$1]+=$8;b[$1]++;}END{for(i=1;i<=(FNR-1);i++)print i,a[i]/b[i];}' avg_x.{$((i+1))..$((i+interval))}.dat
```

It returns error:

```
awk: can't open file avg_x.{1..1000}.dat
```

NOTE:

Lets make it easier:
Even if I do  `cp avg_x.{$((i+1))..$((i+interval))}.dat test/.` It returns:

```
cp: avg_x.{0..1000}.dat: No such file or directory
```

Comment: in order to find files with a digit range, we can use regex to get your file names using `find`, is the value of `i` fixed or changing?

Comment: @ritesht93 if you just define `i` and `interval` and doing what I was doing for copy it will not work. In that case it is fixed. But in my bash script it is changing.

Comment: ohh ok then in that case you'll have to dynamically construct the regex to filter out the digit range

Comment: yeah constructing example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way of doing this is by a horrible concoction of basic commands.

```
i=10
interval=20
awk '<your script here>' $(yes '' | awk '{printf("avg_x%d.dat\n", FNR)}' |\
head -n  $(( $i + $interval )) | tail -n $(( 1 + $interval )) )
```

We can easily demonstrate this using echo in place of awk (I've added some line breaks to make it more readable):

```
$ i=20
$ interval=10
$ echo $(yes '' | awk '{printf("avg_x%d.dat\n", FNR)}' | 
  head -n  $(( $i + $interval )) | tail -n $(( 1 + $interval )) )
avg_x20.dat avg_x21.dat avg_x22.dat avg_x23.dat avg_x24.dat avg_x25.dat 
avg_x26.dat avg_x27.dat avg_x28.dat avg_x29.dat avg_x30.dat
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this inside a loop

```
$ls abcd*
abcd1.txt  abcd2.txt  abcd3.txt  abcd4.txt  abcd5.txt  abcd6.txt  abcd7.txt  
$ regex=$(echo $(seq $((i+1)) $((i+2)) | paste -s -d '|' | sed 's/^/(/g;s/$/)/g'))
$ echo $regex
(2|3)
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname "abcd*" | sed -n -r '/^\.\/abcd'$regex'/p'
./abcd3.txt
./abcd2.txt
```

store the output of above command into an array and expand it using "${array[*]}" while passing it to `awk`

Comment: Thank you for your example, however Vatine one seems more fit for my question:D